# No output value showing up

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

Somehow when running some queries in CF while using existing variables, there is no output showing up. These are the queries:

```
<cfquery name = "group" datasource = "#DSN#">
        SELECT *
        FROM groups
        WHERE ownerid=#user.id#
        ORDER by id
        LIMIT 0, 30
</cfquery>
<cfquery name = "groups" datasource = "#DSN#">
        SELECT *
        FROM group_requests
        WHERE groupid=#group.ownerid#
        ORDER by groupid
        LIMIT 0, 30
</cfquery>

<cfoutput query="groups">
#groupid#
</cfoutput>
```

As you can see first it gets the all the values from the #user.id# and afterwards it uses the value from the first query again in #groep.ownerid#. Somehow this won't show any output value. And yes, there are values to be shown.

Kind regards,

Comment: I assume that the misspelling of "groep.ownerid" is not in the original code? I would also do a <cfdump var="#group#"> to make sure there is values coming from the first query.

Comment: Thanks a lot, figured out the problem afterwards. There was a problem that CF didn't get all the values greater then the first value from the query.

Comment: What you describe as a problem is CF;s default behaviour.  The valuelist() function gets you all the values.  However, for what you are attempting, a single query like the one posted by @Sergii is a better approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess problem is that if 1st query returns multple records only first `group.ownerid` is used -- which can give no matches, or much less than you are expecting.

If results of the 1st query aren't use elsewhere, I would suggest to have it all in the single query. Something like this:

```
<cfquery name = "groups" datasource = "#DSN#">
    SELECT *
    FROM group_requests
    WHERE groupid in
    (
        SELECT ownerid
        FROM groups
        WHERE ownerid = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#user.id#" />
        LIMIT 0, 30
    )
    ORDER by groupid
    LIMIT 0, 30
</cfquery>
```

Also I'm not sure if it makes sense to have two limits here, but there's not enough information to make a meaningful suggestions.

Comment: Another approach is to join tables groups and group_requests.